# Is it ok to write the unicode characters inside string literals in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, unicode

Is it ok to write the following code?

```
const char* str = "§some-text";
```

Will `str` contain the correct UTF-8 representation of the `§` character if the source files was saved in a UTF-8 encoding?

Or is the only way to write it is to use `u8`-prefixed string literals?

Comment: When you save a file with non-UTF8 character, Visual Studio will prompt you to change encoding, and you'd know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you can use Unicode characters in your source code (not just in string literals) is implementation-defined. The only way to be portable is to stick to characters in the "basic source character set" and use `u8"\u00a7some-text"`.

[lex.phases]/1:

> **Physical source file characters are mapped, in an implementation-defined manner, to the basic source character set (introducing new-line characters for end-of-line indicators) if necessary. The set of physical source file characters accepted is implementation-defined.** Any source file character not in the basic source character set (2.3) is replaced by the universal-character-name that designates that character. (An implementation may use any internal encoding, so long as an actual extended character encountered in the source file, and the same extended character expressed in the source file as a universal-character-name (e.g., using the \uXXXX notation), are handled equivalently except where this replacement is reverted in a raw string literal.)

The "basic source character set" is:

> The basic source character set consists of 96 characters: the space character, the control characters representing horizontal tab, vertical tab, form feed, and new-line, plus the following 91 graphical characters:
>
> a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
>
> A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
>
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
>
> _ { } [ ] # ( ) < > % : ; . ? * + - / ^ & | ~ ! = , \ " ’

Comment: And what if I omit the `u8` prefix and write the string literal as `"\u00a7some-text"`?

Comment: @FrozenHeart this is testing my knowledge of how weird source code is handled in C++. I don't know, but this is my guess: characters strings are parsed and then they are converted into an internal encoding. For example, a source file in UTF-16 might be converted into YACE (Yet Another Character Encoding that I just invented) internally. In this case, the two bytes that make up `a` in UTF-16 become the X number of bytes for `a` in YACE. I assume that `\u00a7` becomes the Unicode character SECTION SIGN and that it then converts these bytes to the corresponding character in YACE.

Comment: If you use `u8` then the bytes are in UTF-8 and not YACE (the compiler's internal encoding). Assuming your compiler has an internal encoding of UTF-8, it probably functions exactly the same whether `u8` is present or not.

Comment: Ok, I'll accept this answer and create another one about `u8` rules and such things. Thanks a lot

Comment: @FrozenHeart [lex.phases]/5 "Each source character set member in a character literal or a string literal, as well as each escape
sequence and universal-character-name in a character literal or a non-raw string literal, is converted to
the corresponding member of the execution character set" Backs up my guess somewhat.

Comment: @FrozenHeart The "execution character set" is then converted to UTF-8 if you use a `u8` literal.

Comment: Where did you find information that "The "execution character set" is then converted to UTF-8 if you use a u8 literal"?

Comment: @FrozenHeart [lex.charset]/3 describes the execution character set being an implementation-defined superset of the basic execution character set. And [lex.string]/9 says: "For a UTF-8 string literal, each successive element of the object representation (3.9) has the value of the corresponding code unit of the UTF-8 encoding of the string." Other than the mapping quoted in the answer it doesn't mention it again, but it must obviously convert from its internal encoding to UTF-8 otherwise the `u8` literal is useless.